# Compress existing HDF5 dataset using h5py and free up space without copying or using h5repack

Tags: python, numpy, compression, hdf5, h5py

I'd like to perform an "in-place" compression on certain datasets in an `HDF5` file using the python HDF5 interface `h5py` and reclaim any space possible.

From what I have observed, even after reading the dataset in as a numpy array, then deleting the original dataset in the HDF5, then writing back to the HDF5 file using `compression='gzip'` does not actually free up any space on disk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import h5py
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil

data_sngl = np.ones(shape=(100,100,100), dtype=np.float64)*np.pi

# ===== make uncompressed HDF5 for reference

with h5py.File('data_sngl.h5', 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('data', data=data_sngl, chunks=True)
print('data_sngl.h5 : %0.4f [MB]'%(os.path.getsize('data_sngl.h5')/1000**2))

# ===== make compressed HDF5 for reference

with h5py.File('data_sngl_gz.h5', 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('data', data=data_sngl, chunks=True, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9, shuffle=True)
print('data_sngl_gz.h5 : %0.4f [MB]'%(os.path.getsize('data_sngl_gz.h5')/1000**2))

# ===== attempt 'in-place' compression

shutil.copy2('data_sngl.h5','data_sngl_bak.h5') ## make a copy

with h5py.File('data_sngl.h5', 'r+') as hf: ## open in read/write mode
    data = np.copy(hf['data'][:])
    del hf['data'] ## deleting dataset!

    ### write with compression opts active
    hf.create_dataset('data', data=data, chunks=True, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9, shuffle=True)

print('data_sngl.h5 : %0.4f [MB] --> after in-place compress'%(os.path.getsize('data_sngl.h5')/1000**2))

# ===== 'repack' the in-place compressed file

os.system('h5repack -i data_sngl.h5 -o data_sngl_repacked.h5')
print('data_sngl_repacked.h5 : %0.4f [MB]'%(os.path.getsize('data_sngl_repacked.h5')/1000**2))

# ===== compress while copying to new file

with h5py.File('data_sngl_bak.h5', 'r') as hf:
    data = np.copy(hf['data'][:])
    with h5py.File('data_sngl_copy.h5', 'w') as hfc:
        hfc.create_dataset('data', data=data, chunks=True, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9, shuffle=True)

print('data_sngl_copy.h5 : %0.4f [MB] --> copy compress'%(os.path.getsize('data_sngl_copy.h5')/1000**2))
```

The nominal size of the uncompressed data is about 8.7MB. When initially written to a new hdf5 / new dataset, then the size is much smaller (this is an ideal compression case).

Using an 'in-place' compression, meaning the dataset is copied to memory as a numpy array, then the dataset is deleted using `del`, then the numpy data is written back with compression, the file is still not significantly smaller.

If `h5repack` is run on that file, then space reduction becomes visible.

Alternatively, and unsurprisingly, if the datasets are simply copied to a new HDF5 using `h5py` using compression opts, then the space reduction also becomes visible.

```
data_sngl.h5 : 8.6793 [MB]
data_sngl_gz.h5 : 0.0505 [MB]
data_sngl.h5 : 7.4656 [MB] --> after in-place compress
data_sngl_repacked.h5 : 0.0441 [MB]
data_sngl_copy.h5 : 0.0505 [MB] --> copy compress
```

Is there a way to avoid having to either copy to a new HDF5 or having to call `h5repack` externally? Is there some trick within `h5py` that instructs the HDF5 to 'repack itself', allowing for in-place compression / space re-allocation without having to effectively copy the complete contents of the HDF5 to a new file?

Comment: I am not aware of an "in-place" method to reclaim space in a HDF5 file _**with any API**_.  AFAIK, the HDF5 C code doesn't have this capability. (That's why **The HDF Group** provides `h5repack`.) As a result, a repack function is not in either HDF5 Python package (h5py or PyTables). Note: if you want a Python based repack utility, PyTables has one called `ptrepack`.

Comment: After re-reading your post, I realize there's no need to write any code if you just want to modify compression filters. This can be done with `h5repack` or `ptrepack`. You can compress or uncompress, change the compression level or algorithm  -- no code required.